# Symfony 4: DependencyInjection Component - Uncaught ReflectionException: Class does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm trying to implement the [DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) from Symfony (version 4.0.0) into my project. For this I followed the following simple steps, in order to understand the [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) process:

- In `composer.json`: Assign namespace `App` to the `src` folder.
- In `services.yaml`: Assign namespace `App` to the `src` folder.
- Define `MyController` class in `src` folder, under the namespace `App\Controller`.
- In `bootstrap.php`: Create a `ContainerBuilder` instance (`$container`).
- In `bootstrap.php`: Create a `YamlFileLoader` object and load the config file `services.yaml` into it.
- In `bootstrap.php`: Get an instance of `MyController` from the `$container` and display it on screen.

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class does not exist in <path-to-my-project-root>/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1051
( ! ) ReflectionException: Class does not exist in <path-to-my-project-root>/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1051
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0160  354632  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0166  357928  require_once( '<path-to-my-project-root>/bootstrap.php' ) .../index.php:7
3   0.0872  1752040 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get( )  .../bootstrap.php:16
4   0.0872  1752040 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet( )    .../ContainerBuilder.php:522
5   0.0872  1752816 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService( )    .../ContainerBuilder.php:555
6   0.0873  1752928 __construct ( ) .../ContainerBuilder.php:1051
```

The error occurs at this line (1051) in `ContainerBulder::createService` method, because `$definition->getClass()` returns `NULL`:

```
private function createService(Definition $definition, array &$inlineServices, $id = null, $tryProxy = true) {
    // Line 1051:    
    $r = new \ReflectionClass($class = $parameterBag->resolveValue($definition->getClass()));

    //..
}
```

In the chapter [Automatic Service Loading in services.yaml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example), as I understood it, by using only those settings without any other settings in `services.yaml`, the DI container will know how to create an instance of `MyController`. Maybe I'm wrong?...

Could you please take a second to help me? Thank you very much.

---

My project consists of the following structure and files:

#### Project structure

```
bootstrap.php
composer.json
config/
    services.yaml
src/
    Controller/
        MyController
vendor/
    symfony/
        config/
        dependency-injection/
        filesystem/
        polyfill-mbstring/
        yaml/
```

#### composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.0",
    "symfony/config": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

#### bootstrap.php

```
<?php

use App\Controller\MyController;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$fileLocator = new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/config');
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, $fileLocator);
$loader->load('services.yaml');

$myController = $container->get(MyController::class);

var_dump($myController);
```

#### config/services.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'
```

#### src/Controller/MyController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class MyController {

    public function myAction() {
        echo 'Hello from MyController.';
    }

}
```

---

### Update 1:

After container compilation with `compile()`

```
$loader->load('services.yaml');
$container->compile();
```

I received the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "App\Controller\MyController". in <my-project-path>/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 950
( ! ) Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "App\Controller\MyController". in <my-project-path>/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 950
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.1512  357648  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.1675  361056  require_once( '<my-project-path>/bootstrap.php' )   .../index.php:7
3   3.5621  2582624 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get( ???, ??? ) .../bootstrap.php:18
4   3.5621  2582624 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet( ???, ???, ??? )  .../ContainerBuilder.php:522
```

I checked the `$container->definitions` array following the `compile()` call. I realised that all services (including `App\Controller\MyController`) saved in definitions list prior to `compile()` where removed from the array by the compilation process.

More of it: In `$compiler->passConfig->log` I found these entries (after compilation step):

```
[0] string  "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RemovePrivateAliasesPass: Removed service "Psr\Container\ContainerInterface"; reason: private alias."
[1] string  "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RemovePrivateAliasesPass: Removed service "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface"; reason: private alias."
[2] string  "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\InlineServiceDefinitionsPass: Inlined service "App\Service\MyService" to "App\Controller\MyController"."
[3] string  "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPass: Removed service "App\Controller\MyController"; reason: unused."
[4] string  "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPass: Removed service "App\Service\MyService"; reason: unused."
```

Comment: See if you can add a die statement and determine what $definition->getClass() is returning.  Might be a simple autoload issue though your psr-4 value seems correct.

Comment: Thank you, @Cedar. The `$definition->getClass()` returns `NULL`. For me that seems odd, because I would have expected a class name, or instance, or similar of `MyController`. My composer and autoload are working ok. I can't find the missing piece, if any. Or maybe there's a bug...

Comment: Sure you don't need a $container->compile() before you use it?  I use the framework all the time but have never tried to use the container standalone.  But I'm pretty sure it needs to be compiled.

Comment: @Cerad Oh, that would be a good idea!!! :-) I didn't pay much attention to the compilation part, since I didn't thought it would be necessary outside the framework. I am new to Symfony. Unfortunately is too late now. But I will check it tomorrow and I will certainly give you a feedback. Thank you again! Until tomorrow.

Comment: @Cerad Hi. I tested and debugged. When the container is compiled, and `YamlFileLoader::load` is called, then the `BadMethodCallException('Adding definition to a compiled container is not allowed')` is thrown in `ContainerBuilder::setDefinition`. In general, it seems that a `class` property must be defined in the yaml file. Otherwise the `ReflectionException` (on line 1051) is thrown over and over again. I also looked into the [Changelog](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400). Not even that simple code example is running. I had to define `class: ...` too.

Comment: Compile after calling $loader->load Basically the last step in building the container.

Comment: @Cerad Another good idea. Thanks. I am on testing your proposal now. By the way, I installed the symfony framework as different project and it works as expected, and as I wish to work for my mvc project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160344/discussion-between-aendeerei-and-cerad).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went ahead and setup a fresh project.

There are two issues with your setup.

First you do need to compile the container before using it:

```
// bootstrap.php
$loader->load('services.yaml');

$container->compile();

$myController = $container->get(MyController::class);
```

And then you need to make your controller service public before pulling it from the container:

```
// services.yaml
App\:
    resource: 'src/*'
    exclude: 'src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

App\Controller\:
    resource: 'src/Controller/*'
    public: true
```

This is basically what the framework does.

Comment: It's unbelievable, you really did it !!! :-))) It works indeed !!!!.. I must say, I am very impressed by your perseverance, Cedar! In finding an answer I spent hours and hours... And probably you too spent a lot of time with this task, in order to help me. You made my day and I THANK YOU for your patience! In the next 3 days please accept a 150+ present from me :-) Have a very nice day and I hope to read your answers again. With gratefulness. P.S: Sorry to be late, but I write this message since 25 minute ago :-)) Bye

Comment: Not a problem but thanks.  I was actually waiting for college football to start.  The Reflection error was new to me so I wanted to track it down especially since S4 was just released.  The public/private issue I should have picked up just by reading your question more carefully.

Comment: Oh, trust me, I'll do it with pleasure. And, well, score a few goals in the honour of the new S4! :-)